# .NET Core : the call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: .net-core, error-handling, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity, scaffold

I am working with .NET Core and I try to generate identity scaffold by using CLI:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc entityFramework.Models.MyBlogContext
```

But, when I run this, I get an error:

> Error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderExtensions.AddDefaultTokenProviders(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilder)' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderExtensions.AddDefaultTokenProviders(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilder)'

This is my `Programs.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using entityFrameWorkSQL.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyBlogContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyBlogContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'MyBlogContext' not found.")));
//Add Identity Service
// builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
//                     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyBlogContext>()
//                     .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

//Identity co UI Login, logout, register
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyBlogContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions> (options => { // Truy cập IdentityOptions
    // Thiết lập về Password
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false; // Không bắt phải có số
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false; // Không bắt phải có chữ thường
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false; // Không bắt ký tự đặc biệt
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false; // Không bắt buộc chữ in
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 3; // Số ký tự tối thiểu của password
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1; // Số ký tự riêng biệt

    // Cấu hình Lockout - khóa user
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes (5); // Khóa 5 phút
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5; // Thất bại 5 lầ thì khóa
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

    // Cấu hình về User.
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = // các ký tự đặt tên user
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;  // Email là duy nhất

    // Cấu hình đăng nhập.
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;            // Cấu hình xác thực địa chỉ email (email phải tồn tại)
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;     // Xác thực số điện thoại

});

//Đăng ký Mail Setting vào DI, Mail setting được inject vào SendMailService
builder.Services.AddOptions();
var mailSetting = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings");
builder.Services.Configure<MailSettings>(mailSetting);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, SendMailService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

This is my `entityFrameworkSQL.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.oAuth" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIDConnect" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.11">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.11">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="MimeKit" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You are using Identity package of 2.2, is it migrated from 2.2 version? Try deleting Identity 2.2 and other unnecessary packages.

Comment: Thank for your help !! I had solved the problem

Comment: How did you solve the problem, is it caused by the old version I mentioned?